# Is there script for build on appcenter.ms like pre-build and post-build

Tags: android, flutter, fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

I am building the Flutter app on the appcenter.ms , My build getting completed in appcenter-post-clone.sh itself.

My appcenter-post-clone.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


cd ..

# fail if any command fails
set -e

# debug log
set -x

cd ..

git clone -b 2.5.0 https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH

flutter doctor

echo "Installed flutter to `pwd`/flutter"

flutter build apk --release

#copy the APK where AppCenter will find it
mkdir -p android/app/build/outputs/apk/; mv build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk $_
```

After this, I need to skip other stages(Gradle Task)/Is there any other script to alter the main build steps?